# MongoDB return array of values instead of json

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a following document with `json` as value:
[image].

But `mongodb` returns `array` values instead.

[image]

I am using `jenssegers` plugin for `laravel`.

How can I get `json` value as it is from the table, instead of `arrays`.

I tried `json_encode()` for this case, but there are other similar issues and I want to retrieve the `json` value itself.

Fetching query:

```
$query = \DB::table('v2_reports')
                 ->select('input_controls')
                 ->where('report_key', $report_key)
                 ->first();
```

Comment: What you did for fetching value from the mongodb add here

Comment: @Priyank updated